# Getting a page view element from a model class

Tags: nativescript

I've got a model class and would like to get access to a ui element.

frameModule.topmost().getViewById("id") or

frameModule.topmost().page.getViewById("id")

don't work.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly??? Can you explain more specifically and post some more code?

Comment: I've got ui elements in an xml file (e.g. <Label id="test"/>)...then I have a page file that binds to a model class (derives from Observable). In a method in the model class, I'm trying to get access to the Label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand what you need, I hope this solution would help.

In XML, assuming that you have UI Element with an ID. You will get it in the controller. For example:

In `page.xml`:

```
<Label id="test"/>
```

In the binding object class in `page-view-model.js`, create a property that has type of label:

```
var labelModule = require("ui/label");
var Label = labelModule.Label;

class Someclass extends Observable {
    public label: Label;
}
```

In `page.js`:

```
function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var myLabel = page.getViewById("test");
    var context = new Someclass();
    page.bindingContext = context;
    context.label = myLabel;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to get access to the page object in the model class (via frame) - but this works also. Thanks.

Comment: Update...for those wanting to access the page object in the model class - assuming that's done on a UI event callback. You can do something similar to (pseudo code) - `(<Label>eventArg).page`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get a reference to the `Page` object. The documentation is a good reference to learn about them: https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/page#page-reference

To answer you question, the usual way to get a reference to the `Page` object inside a view model class is by using the `EventData` passed to each event like a `tap` event when a `Button` is tapped.

```js
onButtonTap(args: EventData) {
  const button = args.object as Button;
  const page = button.page;
  // ...
}
```